# How to over come case-senstivity of file names in Ant

Tags: ant

I am using `<zip> and <zipfileset>` for zipping the files

File system contains file name `abc.txt`and if my ant script contains file name `Abc.txt` the script does not pick up this file instead complains file `Abc.txt` not found

Any idea how I can over come this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the `casesensitive` attribute of [FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) and by extension [ZipFileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) to meet your requirement.  This is `true` by default.

Answer (score 2):

put `casesensitive="false"` in zipfileset or zip.Both supports casesensitive attribute.It is true by default.
Hope that will help.